# iPhone Contacts App Examples

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking for references on how to reproduce the iPhone Contacts App.

Ideally it would be in one resource: book, video, tutorial, etc.

But I realize that me be too much to ask for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely read over Apple's [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1) on the Address Book. This question also addresses your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558543/iphone-address-book-sample-code

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out this tutorial? http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/09/19/access-the-address-book/

Answer (score 1):

I reimplemented ABPersonViewController. This may be helpful: [SSPersonViewController](https://github.com/samsoffes/sspersonviewcontroller).